# Vim: Add two lines after auto shebang

Tags: vim

I have set my .vimrc to automatically add a shebang line, as below:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * execute 'silent! 1s/.*/#!\/usr\/bin\/env ' . (empty(&filetype) ? '' : ' '.&filetype)
```

However, I would like it to also add two lines below it and go into insert mode. When I simply add $i to the end of the command, as below, I get an error. Ideas?

```
autocmd BufNewFile * execute 'silent! 1s/.*/#!\/usr\/bin\/env ' . (empty(&filetype) ? '' : ' '.&filetype) $<CR><CR>i
```

Comment: You're trying to use normal commands in your `:exe`. For this you need to use `norm`  or `feedkeys`. For example try replacing `$<cr><cr>i` with `| call feedkeys("A\<cr>\<cr>")` (untested).

Comment: @Sergio: Changing to insert mode is special; instead of the generic `feedkeys()`, better use the dedicated `:startinsert` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * if !empty(&filetype) | execute 'silent! 1s/.*/#!\/usr\/bin\/' . &filetype . '\r\r'| :startinsert | endif
```

Btw, neat thinking, I'm adding this to my vimrc :)